# How to pass parameters to XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, parameters, parameter-passing

I have a problem.

I have an XML file that contains information about 100 courses.

I have an XSL file that nicely displays the list of 100 courses.

But what if I want to only display 1 course.  Can I pass a parameter to the XSLT file to tell it to only display "ENGL 100" ?

The XML looks something like this:

```
<document>
<menu>
   <item>
      <name>MTH 300</name>
      <brief>Mathematics Skill Development</brief>
      <description>A course in the fundamentals of ...</description>
   </item>
   <item>
      <name>MTH 301</name>
      <brief>Basic Algebra</brief>
      <description>An introduction to algebra, ...</description>
   </item>
 ...
```

I know I could write an XSLT file called "eng100.xsl" to loop through the XML and display only ENG 100 but I don't want to have to write dozens of these files.

The XML is dynamic and I am able to control it.  I want the XSLT file to be static and never change.

Is there any way to pass parameters into the XSLT?

Comment: Please note that the answer depends in part on which XSLT engine you're using and how you're invoking it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can pass parameters to XSLT, how this is done depends on your XSLT processor, but usually as additional command arguments, if it's a command-line processor.

You declare parameters using

```
  <xsl:param name="courseName" select"initialValue"/>
```

You can then test this parameter in your XSLT, and invoke a different template depending on it's value. For example, if the parameter is empty, then invoke the current template that processes all elements, otherwise invoke a template that only processes elements when the item name equals the parameter value. You can do this with a test

```
   <xsl:template match="item">
      <xsl:if test="$courseName=name(./name)">
         <xsl:call-template name="yourOriginalTemplate"/>
      </xsl:if>
   </xsl:template>
```

But by filtering and formatting, you are mixing two concerns in one file. I would separate out the selection of the XML elements from formatting - have two xslt files for that and run them as a pipeline.

Comment: Also, for some scenarios, you could use a "metadata" input document that drive the transformation and access "data" document with `document()` function. This will cost in efficiency.

Comment: What if the xml document has a processing instruction <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="mytransformation.xsl"?> Is it possible to pass the xsl parameter to the xml file by url-encoded name=value parameter? I mean, can i do something like this then: mycontent.xml?courseName=MTH300

Answer (score 0):

Very old question I know -but just in case it helps somebody.
If you are using any server-side scripting engine - consider using HTTP Params: you can link to the XSL like this (assuming a PHP backend here)

```
<?xml-stylesheet href="myxsl.xsl.php?my_param=abc" type="text/xsl"?>
```

Note the renamed file to '[...].xsl.php' - and we'll need to set 'content-type' back to 'xml' as well:

The contents of the XSL can then be mixed with a small amount of server-side code to set up an XSL variable.
For example:

```
<?php header('Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8'); ?>
[...]
<xsl:variable name="my_param"><?=$_GET[my_param']?></xsl:variable>
```