# XSLT: Giving different views of the data

Tags: javascript, html, css, xml, xslt

This is a "best design approach" question more than a coding question. I'm looking for the best approach to filtering data in XSLT. I have a blog which is generated from XML, XSLTand CSS. Each blog post falls under a category - Week 1, Week 2 or Week 3.

[image]

At the moment, I'm displaying all the categories on the side. When I click WEEK1, I want to show only posts from Week 1. Is this any way to do this without having an XML file for each week?

As a sideline... this is a demo of what XSLT can do. Something like php would have been much better suited for the job, but this needs to be done with XSLT/HTML/JavaScript/CSS.

If the question is not clear, please ask and I will do my best to rephrase it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be many approaches.

The fastest should be: Give every post a className related to the week(e.g. `post week1`,`post week2`, etc.)

When you click on a link on the side, give the common anchestor of all posts also a class, related to the clicked Week, e.g. `posts week1`

All you need now is a little bit of css:

```
.posts .post{
  display:none;
}
.posts.week1 .post.week1,
.posts.week2 .post.week2,
.posts.week3 .post.week3{
  display:block;
}
```

Comment: Fastest for whom? The bigger the XML grows, the slower the page will be to load and process.

Comment: I think he meant fastest development time probably. Anyway, thanks! Didn't think of this approach.

Comment: I did not mean the development time at first. When using multiple xml-files is not an option, of course the loading process of the page will increase, but this will not have any effect to my suggestion, because it will always only set the className of 1 node, no matter how may entries the blog will have. Any other approach would need a kind of loop, what will be affected by the size of the xml-file.

Comment: My point was that you need to put _all_ the posts into the page even though you may never display them all during the lifetime of the page.

Answer (score 0):

If you want demonstrate what xslt can do, perhaps a simple xpath query like **//WEEKS[.="WEEK1"]** for example can be sufficient

Comment: Indeed, it's not enough to resolve your problem, I thought that you want only "Week1" :) Another way is to write links on you categories which run a javascript when you click. I see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011013/using-a-single-xsl-file-to-display-different-elements) or [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10260331/mouse-click-xslt) with this problematic

Answer (score 0):

This is where XLink would come in handy, unfortunately browser support is still pathetic.

What i would try is pre-processing the XML with JS and XPath, so it only contains the week you want. Then send only that XML into the `XSLTProcessor()`, so it'll only put out those. You may have to assemble the whole HTML document outside of XSL then though - not sure.

You could also [send XML parameters as parameters into the processor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3251149/how-to-pass-parameters-to-xslt) and use them in your transformation.

But in the end, it's still inefficient to send the whole XML over the wire, if you're only going to show a fraction of it. So, a server-side solution to generate only the XML that's actually needed would be better.

Last but not least, maybe have a look at [Saxon-CE](http://www.saxonica.com/ce/index.xml).